# Passing indexPath between collectionviews

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, swift3

I am trying to pass `indexPath` of the cell that user taps so when the segue performs `collectionView` scrolls to the correct cell. But I am stuck and I don't know what i am doing wrong. Here is my code:

FIRST VIEW CONTROLLER

```
var selectedRow = 0

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        selectedRow = indexPath.row
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "indexPath", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "indexPath") {
            let nextVC = segue.destination as! ViewController3
            nextVC.mySelectedRow = selectedRow
        }

    }
```

SECOND VIEW CONTROLLER

```
    var mySelectedRow = 0

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.myCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: mySelectedRow, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
    }
```

I am getting an error in this line.

```
self.myCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: mySelectedRow, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
```

Comment: When asking for help with an error you need to include the exact error that you are getting, and state wether it's a compile-time error or a runtime error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method [`scrollToItem(at:at:animated:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionview/1618046-scrolltoitem) want `IndexPath` as first argument not the `Int`. So either create `IndexPath` object from that mySelectedRow instance or you need to pass `IndexPath` object instead of `Int`.

If you doesn't know the section you want scroll in `collectionView` than you need to pass indexPath instead of just passing row.

**FIRST VIEW CONTROLLER**

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "indexPath", sender: indexPath)


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "indexPath") {
        let nextVC = segue.destination as! ViewController3
        nextVC.mySelectedIndexPath = sender as! IndexPath
    }
}
```

**SECOND VIEW CONTROLLER**

```
var mySelectedIndexPath = IndexPath()

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.myCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: mySelectedIndexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
}
```

If you know the section you want scroll in `collectionView` than simply this will work.

```
self.myCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(row: mySelectedRow, section: 0), at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
```

Comment: Yes got it. I have created a new segue from view controller to another view controller instead of from cell to view controller. Anyway thank you very much for your help and patience!!

Comment: @Volkan Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 0):

Use like this :

```
self.myCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath.init(row: mySelectedRow, section: 0), at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
```

Comment: Better yet do what Nirav says, and past the whole IndexPath rather than just the row, since collection views tend to use both row and section.